# Nginx timeout in docker-swarm

Tags: docker-swarm

The docker-compose.yml posted below to bring up a simple nginx-Container works perfectly fine with

```
docker-compose up
```

But if I bring it up in docker-swarm with

```
docker stack deploy -c=docker-compose.yml nginx
```

I just get a timeout trying to reach the nginx...
Any ideas how to debug this or what could be the cause?

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - 80:80
```

Comment: Have you tried to exec into the container and check the nginx logs?

Comment: @Trevor The logs are linked in the nginx-container to stdout and stderr. So they should appear in the docker logs from my understanding. docker logs and docker service logs for the respective container/service however just yields empty output...